# How to fix the distribution error for win32 package

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pywin32

I was trying to install win32 module for python 3.7 for printing files by printers in my code

I used pip and also visited the page of the package on web. by using pip pywin32 it gives error no 11004. I used ways below in cmd.

```
pip install pywin32
python -m pip install pywin32
```

I expected that it will be installed properly but unlike the other packages that I installed and went alright, this one gives error that "error 11004, getaddrinfo failed"
thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked if you are behind a proxy?